# Binding SWT List to an ArrayList

Tags: java, data-binding, swt

I am trying to bind an ArrayList of objects to a Java SWT List widget. This is what I have:

```
    DataBindingContext bindingContext = new DataBindingContext();
    //
    myModel= new WritableList(buses, MyObject.class); 
    IObservableList listWidgetObs = SWTObservables.observeItems(listWidget);
    bindingContext.bindList(listWidgetObs , myModel, null, null);
    //
    return bindingContext;
```

But somehow, it doesn't seem to work. I have been trying for a long time but still with no luck. This is my first time trying data binding in Java. How do I bind an ArrayList as the data provider of an SWT List widget and then bind it to the value of a method call getName() in MyObject class?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `it doesn't seem to work` mean? Is there an error or is the data not being bound together?

Comment: Nothing happens. The list just doesn't show any thing. Just an empty list.

Comment: Ok, so no exception is thrown. Are you sure the ArrayList contains data? Can you provide a larger code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, it looks like the model list (`myModel`) contains objects of type `MyObject`. But this is wrong as the content list of an SWT `List` must by be Strings.

You have (at least) three choices:

- the objects in the list must be of type `String` so you must convert the objects as you create the observable list, or
- your must supply a `UpdateListStrategy` in `bindingList(...)`, or
- you bind with a `ListViewer` with a `LabelProvider`

The choice depends on whether the objects of `myModel` can change dynamically.

I usually choose the second option when possible as I try to not mix both databinding and JFace unless it is really, really needed. The alternative can sometimes get some rather ugly notification/listener chains...

Comment: I also use a UpdateListStrategy approach, but for some reason, the Target->Model strategy does not work! Any ideas? The Model->Target works just fine. I use a SWTObservables.observeItems(list).

Comment: Sorry, but no easy answer here. I need to study the code see what is wrong.

Comment: Can you confirm this: when the SWT LIST observed with SWTObservables.observeItems() changes (element ADD/REMOVE, etc), the targetToModelConverter should fire, right?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure how you will add elements to the SWT List. I have not checked, but I think the binding to List.items is one way only.

Comment: Yes... it is... no luck with that approach. I resolved the issue with a SWTObservables.observeSingleSelectionIndex and a Integer->List (Target->Model) Converter. Thanks!